# Closing Bootstrap Modal form after a Successful Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

My modal form successfully makes an Ajax request. The data received is displayed in the background. Invoking the modal is done by data-* attributes as bootstrap examples show [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). But the modal is not getting dismissed. I tried to add

```
OnSuccess = "$('#searchForm').modal('hide');"
```

to my Ajax.BeginForm. But this doesn't remove the fade effect that modal cast on the background.

My View is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="searchForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="searchFormLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="searchFormLabel">Search Here</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "results",
                    OnSuccess = "$('#searchForm').modal('hide');"
                }))
                {
                    // input fields and submit button are here
                }
            </div>

           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: After `$('#searchForm').modal('hide');` add this `$('.modal-backdrop').hide();`. See if it works.

Comment: @Alorika It works, but the next time you try to open the modal it will be dismissed immediately.

Comment: That may occur due to event bubbling. So you can try adding `e.stopPropagation()` after `$('#searchForm').modal('hide');`. See if this solution works for you.

Comment: Sorry. I tried:
OnSuccess = "$('#searchForm').modal('hide'); $('.modal-backdrop').hide(); e.stopPropagation();"

 It didn't work.

Comment: See it did not work because `e` will be undefined in this case. You need to specify a function on `OnSuccess` like `OnSuccess="callMyfunction"`. Then in that function (`function callMyFunction(e)`) put this `$('#searchForm').modal('hide');e.stopPropagation();`. Try this way.

Comment: I have modified OnSuccess as:

 OnSuccess = "unloadModal"

Down the page the function is declared as:

var unloadModal = function (e) {
        $('#searchForm').modal('hide');
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99171/discussion-between-alorika-and-vivekanand-p-v).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you are opening up the `modal` via `data-attributes`, and then closing it using jQuery. So, in a way both modal toggling methods are used, which are conflicting with each other. So, remove the data-attributes and show/hide the `modal` using jQuery only.

Try this:

```
$('#searchForm').modal('show'); //for showing the modal
```

For hiding on OnSuccess:

```
OnSuccess = "unloadModal"
```

Function `unloadModal` will be:

```
function unloadModal() {
    $('#searchForm').modal('hide');
};
```

Comment: Also was helpful for me :)

Comment: @MazdakShojaie- Glad it heped you too :)

Answer (score 1):

My scenario: Providing content of Bootstrap modal through MVC partial view and using Ajax POST-call in it.
What solved my case with automatically closing the modal after ajax-call is completed is a little "combo" of calls in the OnComplete/OnSuccess handler function:

```
function onAjaxCompleted()
{
    $('#searchForm.close').click(); 
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
}
```

Hope this might help you as well.