# Unload Modal after data processed in datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I show modal while processing data in my datatable, however i can't figure out how to hide the modal after the process is done.
I checked and tried all [events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) of datatable with no sucess

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var x = $('#datatab').DataTable({
               .....
     });

    $('#datatab').on('processing.dt', function (e, settings) {
                alert("processing");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('show'); // Here i show the modal
            });
            // I tried the following events but non worked
            $('#datatab').on('draw.dt', function () {
                alert("draw");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            });



            $('#datatab').on('stateLoaded.dt', function () {
                alert("stateLoaded");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            });

            $('#datatab').on('initComplete', function () {
                alert("initComplete");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            });

            $('#datatab').on('stateLoadParams.dt', function () {
                alert("stateLoadParams");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            });

            $('#datatab').on('xhr.dt', function () {
                alert("xhr");
                $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            });
```

The model remains open, how can i hide it after the processing is done?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like from the docs `initComplete` is an option you provide when setting up the table.  Have you tried using `$('#datatab').on('init.dt' , function(){ ... };` instead?

Comment: Yes i did, and it doesn't hide the Modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me

```
var x = $('#datatab').DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "beforeSend":AjaxBegin,
                "type": "POST",
                "url": '/Totto/GetZScgData',
                "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data': function(data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); },
                'complete': AjaxComplete
            },

function AjaxBegin() {
    $('#myPleaseWait').modal('show');

}
function AjaxComplete() {
    $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Set timeout to hide the model.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');},100)
```

Comment: I want the modal to be hidden after all data loaded, this canno't be fixed timeout

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you can use $.ajax() OnSuccess attribute to hide it,if you want

kindly refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506411/3397630

Hope above information was useful , kindly let me know your thoughts

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: thanks for your answer.
By adding onSuccess, it stops all other events from firing, so Onsuccess events fires before the progress event.